# Hibernate : Union of two queries that return different type of objects

Tags: hibernate, union

I have two classes which are unrelated to each other, mapped to two separate DB tables. I want to retrieve two objects from one table and two from another in SINGLE DB hit. I tried something as follows:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select i from ReconcileInterface i where i.AID in ('1-1-2') "
    + " union select d from ReconcileDevice d where d.TID in ('NPHLOHTAPPANLAKE688') " );

List<? extends Object> records = query.list();

for (Object value : records) {
    if (value instanceof ReconcileInterface) {
        System.out.println("Interface:" + ((ReconcileInterface)value).getAID());
    } else if (value instanceof ReconcileDevice) {
        System.out.println("Device:" + ((ReconcileDevice) value).getTID());
    }
}
```

However, the result retrieved to not contains results for the second sub query above (but it does return data as an independent query).

If this is not the right way, I would like to know how can I query for two unrelated objects in a single DB hit. Please note that these two classes do not have any relation or any common base class. This is being tried out only to reduce the number of DB hits as I know that each time I need objects from both tables.

Comment: You can't. As simple as that. Just execute two queries. And don't use `in` where `=` can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the original code has multiple values in the IN clause (in the example, the list was shortened). But I feel this would have been a useful feature in Hibernate (to be able to reduce no. of DB hits).

Comment: Even in SQL you can't use union to execute two sql queries returning a different set of columns.

Comment: Agreed, but in SQL you can manipulate the sets of columns to become equivalent and while parsing you can interpret them the way you want (Eg. in query you can cast an integer to a string just to match it with the column type from other set and in code you can cast it back to int)